# Rewrite rule for different api versions

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite, slim

I'm looking for an RewriteRule for my Slim Api to put in the .htaccess that allow me to use different api version, something like:

```
i.e.
v1/something -> v1/index.php
v1/something/something -> v1/index.php

i.e.
v2/something-> v2/index.php
v2/something/something -> v2/index.php

i.e.
p_v1/something-> p_v1/index.php
p_v1/something/something -> p_v1/index.php
```

The project folders structure is the follow:

- api

  - p_v1
  - v1
  - v2

    - index.php
    - others...

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Edit**

This one is working fine:

```
RewriteRule ^ v1/index.php [QSA,L]
```

But is working only with the v1 (as expected), i need to find something that works with every version of the api.

**Edit 2**

For now i've found one workaround adding manually each new api version:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^v1/(.*)$ v1/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p_v1/(.*)$ p_v1/index.php
```

But i'm still looking for something automated.

Comment: use instruction like nginx `try_files` for apache2, you can say apache2 for example you can see this question http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files

Comment: I don't understand how this can be applied on my problem, can you make me an example of this?

Comment: sorry ( I don't finish understand you question.

Comment: I don't see how i can use nginx to fix my problem..

Comment: I say this like nginx instruction `try_files` its just for example. You need `RewriteCond` derictive http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: okay, now i understand that it could help me.. I'm trying to see how to use it for my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined that the original request URI following the initial version designation is handled by this rule, so I'm assuming your script at index.php handles that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-z0-9_\.\-]+)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php [NC]
```

NB. This takes any alphanumeric character (plus underscore and hyphen) before the first slash and uses that as the directory to serve from. It also allows for a request without anything following the version designator (like `http://example.api.com/v1/`)

Comment: Yes, Slim Fragmework is handling eveything, i just need to redirect to the correct index.php in realtion to the version of the request. What you gave me is what i need, but is giving me 500 error..

Comment: I've added an edit to the question with something that is working fine.. but is still not fixing my problem, thanks

Comment: @dvdciri - Sorry, that'll teach me to not read what I've typed properly. Edited and should work now.
NB. I've added a literal . (dot) to the matched chars before the slash, just in case you wanted `http://example.api.com/v1.1/something`

Comment: Okay, it works of i've got something like this `website.com/p_v1/wishes` but not if i've got this `website.com/p_v1/user/login` .. i have a 500 error with the last one

Comment: @dvdciri - Edited. Fixed. (promise) :)